# How to create flexible D3 svg polyline

Tags: d3.js, svg

I create polyline like this

```
sampleSVG.append("polyline")     
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .style("fill", "none")
    .attr("points", "10,10,15,10,15,30,30,30");
```

I want to change this polyline shape after drag middle of the polyline.How to add this funtionality to polyline.Do I need to delete current polyline and create new one according to changes or is there any way to do this?

[image]

Comment: you could use the SVG DOM to add a new point to the polyline: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#InterfaceSVGPointList